# object is not subscriptable with dictionary trying to print dictionary converted using .items

Tags: python

Currently trying to print the first entry of alphabet_numbers.items (a, 1)?

```
alphabet_numbers = {'a': '1', 
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3', 
    'd'  : '4',
    'e': '5'
}

tuple1 = alphabet_numbers.items()


print(tuple1[0,0])
```

how can print only first entry of tuple1?

If put `print(tuple1)` I get:

```
dict_items([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4'), ('e', '5')])
```

Comment: `tuple1` is probably not the best name for that variable. But anyway, you could do either `list(tuple1)[0]` or `next(iter(tuple1))`. The first is probably easier to understand, but the second uses less memory if you started with a big dictionary.

Comment: Make it a list: `tuple1 = list(alphabet_numbers.items())` ?

Comment: I suppose the obvious question is: if you want to access this data by numeric index like an ordered collection, why don't you make an ordered collection like a list? While  dictionaries now preserve key order, they aren't made for ordered access. This is why you need to jump through these hoops to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be explicitly converted to a list:

```
alphabet_numbers = {'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3',
    'd': '4',
    'e': '5'
}

tuple1 = list(alphabet_numbers.items())
print(tuple1[0][0])

print(list(alphabet_numbers.keys())[0])
```

Or use function `keys`, if you are only interested in the first key.

Function `items` does not return a list, but a view like object.
The type checker `mypy` reveals the type by using `reveal_type(tuple1)` of the original example:

```
typing.ItemsView[builtins.str*, builtins.str*]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first_entry = list(alphabet_numbers.items())[0]
```

You can print the first entry and it will output a tuple.